# No symmetries in the universe at the Big Bang...?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, symmetry, big-bang, cosmological-inflation

I apologize in advance if this is a stupid question but...

According to some scenarios about the beginning of the universe (namely cosmological inflation), in layman terms, everything was born out of a quantum fluctuation which caused a violent expansion. In this case, since an expanding universe break the time translation symmetry, energy conservation does not necessarily hold and therefore energy and matter could have appeared from """nowhere""" (https://youtu.be/ZjTrWSkkD8I)

However, if these conditions were "repeated" in a spacetime with no (global) symmetries, could all conservation laws and the rest fundamental laws of physics have been also violated or approximate? Would this be theoretically possible?

Comment: I'm curious to know what other people have to say, but I've personally always hated the "a quantum fluctuation" phrasing. It's not genuinely a phenomenon that arises in quantum mechanics. An electron in the groundstate of the hydrogen atom isn't having its position "quantum fluctuating" around the proton. Its state is described by an unmoving wavefunction. But I find even real physicists using this phrasing to explain real phenomena, for example the Wikipedia for fine structure says "the Darwin term comes from the quantum fluctuating motion or zitterbewegung of the electron" which is wrong

Comment: There are a lot of problems with hypotheses about the "beginning of the universe". What rapid inflation does under a pedestrian interpretation of quantum mechanics is not to cause quantum fluctuations. It merely selects one of an infinite number of possible quantum states (at least in some approximation) and then amplifies that to macroscopic scale. To me that's not a very meaningful physical statement since we can't repeat the "universe experiment", hence there is no way to actually sample and reconstruct anything resembling a wave function. But that's just my personal taste.